# Disable caja terminal

Tags: mate-desktop, caja

Caja has a tendency of leaving zombie terminal processes behind, which is a nuisance when working with removable media. Caja pops up when the media is inserted, but then it is impossible to unmount and eject media as the zombie bash has an open handle on it. Is it possible to disable the terminal part of caja permanently?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to uninstall `caja-terminal`

```
sudo dnf remove caja-terminal
```

Comment: Is `caja-terminal` correct? I don't have `caja-terminal` in my repo, only `caja-open-terminal`.